# Change pickup order on a 5-way blade switch

Tags: guitar, wiring

I'm going to be following the following set up for my telecaster's controller:
https://sixstringsupplies.co.uk/pages/5-way-telecaster-wiring

But I don't like the default order of the selection.

I want to have:

1. Neck
2. Neck with series cap
3. Neck & Bridge parallel
4. Neck & Bridge HOOP
5. Bridge

Is this possible? And how do I work out the wiring order on the switch to match this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that unless I miss some smart solution, this is impossible with a standard 5-way blade switch.

Please see this explanation of how a 5-way switch works:
http://alloutput.com/guitar/5-way-switches-explained/
or
https://www.fralinpickups.com/2017/06/18/blade-switch-basics/
[image]

In particular, I think that with a regular switch, the "pickup with series cap" and "HOOP" need to be next to each other, as both of them use a capacitor.

Some producers make switches which offer more possibilities for connections. With some googling I was able to find e.g. these:

- Schaller Megaswitches https://schaller.info/en/megaswitches
- Grigsby Superswitch [https://www.stewmac.com/video-and-ideas/online-resources/learn-about-guitar-pickups-and-electronics-and-wiring/super-switch-installation-and-wiring/|](https://www.stewmac.com/video-and-ideas/online-resources/learn-about-guitar-pickups-and-electronics-and-wiring/super-switch-installation-and-wiring/%7C)
- Freeway switches https://www.freewayswitch.com/schematics-blade/

I'm sorry, but I cannot find a specific solution for you at this time, but perhaps you would be able to find a switch that allows you to make the connections you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for a, though disappointing, clear answer. You've saved me a lot of time trying to do the impossible.